# How to identify Stripe webhooks type?

Tags: stripe-payments, webhooks

I am using Stripe and I need to understand how to only process webhooks that are generated by Stripe behind the scenes. When my server sends something to Stripe (new subscription, new individual charge) Stripe will generate events that are sent via the webhooks I provide. Well, I don't need to process those since it will create a mess. I only want to process Stripe generated webhooks in situations like: failed charge at subscription renewal, manual modifications via the Stripe dashboard, refunds generated in the dashboard, etc).

I went through the events generated and I cannot find anything that would make a difference from those my API calls generate or those generated behind the scenes.

Is there something I am missing?

**Update**
- API call: event has a `request` id
- Stripe behind the scenes: event has `null` request_id
- Stripe dashboard: event has a `request` id **(This still remains a problem)**

If I discard all webhook events that are `not null` I will also discard Stripe dashboard events. I need to process Stripe behind the scenes and also Stripe dashboard generated events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, Stripe currently does not support identifying the incoming webhook event type. Looking in the Dashboard I indeed can see what initiated the event (API, Dashboard or Automatic) but Stripe's people said they don't support it.

However, there is a workaround. For anyone struggling with this I will describe what I did. An automatic Stripe generated event is easy to differentiate. It contains a `null` `request` field. Any other type of event will have a `request id` (ex: re_123h2kj18321hjk3218). The problem remains with differentiating between API and Stripe Dashboard generated requests. Therefore, the solution is to capture the request id for every request generated by the API. Whenever a webhook arrives to your server, you check for the request field NOT to be in the Storage System (DB, etc) OR that the request is null. This means that the event was generated by either the Dashboard or Automatically by Stripe (subscription renewal).

Steps:

- Hook into the CurlClient provided by Stripe. Extend that class and
  override the request() method. The request method returns the
  response generated by Stripe servers. Capture the `headers` of the
  response which would contain a `Request-id`. Store that in your
  Storage (in my case a DB)
- In your configuration files you need to specify that Stripe should use your own CurlClient. `ApiRequestor::setHttpClient(new CurlClient());` (I've named my CurlClient too but you can name it whatever)
- When a webhook arrives, you have three options to identify the type:

  1. Automatic: if the event has a `request=null`
  2. Dashboard: the `request is not null` and the request is not in you Storage
  3. API: you're left with one situation. The request is not null but exists in your DB

As you can see, there's quite a lot of work for something really easy. All Stripe needs to do is provide another field in their webhook event name something like `request-type` with three options (api, automatic, dashboard). They already have this build but they don't allow it to be shown in the webhook event.

Answer (score 1):

On the event object [documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/api#event_object), you'll see the `request` property [documented](https://stripe.com/docs/api#event_object-request). This property is set whenever the event came from an API request. Otherwise, if it's `null` it means there was no API request associated with it and it was what we call an Automatic event in the dashboard.

You need to discard any event where `request` is not `null` on your end!

Comment: I am getting closer. you are right. Stripe behind the scenes does indeed generate a `null` request. However, one problem still remains. Any "manual" action taken in the Stripe Dashboard will generate an event with a `request_id`. Since I will discard all webhooks where the request is not null I will therefore discard any action taken in Stripe dashboard. Is it possible to make a difference between a API generate request and one generated from the Dashboard?

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to do anything like this unfortunately. The best solution here is to have your code set metadata on the objects you create or modify so that anything without metadata happened in the dashboard or automatically.

Comment: In the end I found a way that is working. Thankfully I got some help on #stripe IRC channel at freenode.